# Sum of two fields

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a mysql table with 2 fields: `numPears`(int) and `numApples`(int) and i'd like to have a `numFruit`(int) that automatically get these 2 values and sum them. Is that possible?

**Example**

So that if a query

```
INSERT INTO strange_table (fruitID, numPears, numApples) VALUES (1, 1, 5);
```

And then query

```
SELECT numFruit FROM strange_table WHERE fruitID = 1;
```

It returns me `6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create a static value every time a new row comes into the DB, use a trigger.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html and in particular, triggers on insert and update.

-- You've clarified your question!  I think stored procedures are more what you are looking for now!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

This lets you create a function inside MySQL called numFruit which returns the sum of the other two columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (numPears + numApples) AS numFruit FROM strange_table WHERE fruitID = 1;
```

Comment: Can i also select something else in that sql statement?

Comment: Yes, just add a comma after 'numFruit' and add the additional columns you wish to retrieve:- SELECT (numPears + numApples) AS numFruit, numPears, numApples FROM strange_table WHERE fruitID = 1;

Comment: Cannot select this as an accepted answer because it is a twist-question answer. But it as been very usefull. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP

```
$pears = 5;
$apples= 1;

$query = "INSERT INTO strange_table (fruitID, numPears, numApples, numFruit) VALUES (1, $pears, $apples, " . ($pears + $apples) . ")";
```

Comment: Well, the two `numPears` and `numApples`, in my case, will be surely updated separately later, so i should also select the `numFruit` field and update it again using at least 1 more query.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called a "computed column"  It doesn't look like MySql currently supports those.